# AndroidStudio : attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android

I'm working on a android studio project for school, just trying to get a camera app working, and I got these problems :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{univ.iut.acy.rt2.bartg.firstapp/univ.iut.acy.rt2.bartg.firstapp.CamActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3340)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7476)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:939)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at univ.iut.acy.rt2.bartg.firstapp.CamActivity.onCreate(CamActivity.java:26)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7989)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3315)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7476) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:939)

**Here is the CamActivity.java :**

```
  public class CamActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnCamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much, it's my first time trying to get help from anyone here !

Comment: Add your layout. Most likely the button ID is wrong or missing.

Comment: you've NPE at `Button btnCamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);` check this button id at `R.layout.activity_main`

Comment: Hey, i'm sorry, i dont really understand. Here's my activity_main.xml :


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/validate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="validate"
        android:text="@string/validate"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/ip"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ip"/>


What could be wrong with my ID button ?